# Animated bar chart race, a popular data visualization

Tags: graphics, dynamic, data, animation, gif-format

[image]

Recently I see more and more data-viz called "Animated bar chart race". Some random examples, and **note, how smoothly and organically everything changes in these videos.**:

- https://flourish.studio/visualisations/bar-chart-race
- https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/qmklqh/oc_how_dangerous_cleaning_the_chernobyl_reactor
- https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-an-animated-bar-chart-race-with-tableau-6a7839f703af

I hope there is a trick to adopt `BarChart` for this. But nothing comes to mind than quite direct and elaborate hijacking of rectangles from `BarChart`

```
Cases[BarChart[{1,2,3}],_Rectangle,Infinity]
```

> {Rectangle[{0.548798,0.},{1.4512,1.},RoundingRadius->0], Rectangle[{1.5488,0.},{2.4512,2.},RoundingRadius->0], Rectangle[{2.5488,0.},{3.4512,3.},RoundingRadius->0]}

and doing some tedious time dependent moving of coordinates. It is not clear to me how one can very comprehensively select a speed of rectangle motion and what is the best data structure to be fed into `BarChartRace` function. Do I provide just "frames" of data samples (which seems ideal, with a lot of automation figuring out the animation rates and looks) or do I need to provide some time stamps etc.? Also, note, not only the bars length is affected, but the identity of each bar and plot range need to be tracked, for example here are two sequential frames where lengths changed and bars moved which is the elementary thing that needs to be animated:

```
{BarChart[{1,2,3},ChartStyle->{Red,Green,Blue},PlotRange->7],
BarChart[{3.5,4,7},ChartStyle->{Blue,Green,Red},PlotRange->7]}
```

[image]

I did not try yet to deep, because I keep thinking that maybe there is a package already somewhere or a few neat tricks to make this work easily that folks here are aware of. Any solution is highly-highly appreciated.

### Tentative basic scenario

Questionable, but in mind mind it looks something like... At a given moment we have some example data (like number of animals) - called ***data-frame***. We got more dogs than cats, so dog bar is 1st by rank in the data-viz:

```
<|"cat"->5,"dog"->7|>
```

Some growth or decrease happens. ***Event 1*** leading to swapping of bars is that rankings changed, now we got more cats than dogs and the cat's bar is 1st in data-viz:

```
<|"cat"->11,"dog"->8|>
```

Another type of event is introduction of a new player (bird):

```
<|"cat"->13,"dog"->11,"bird"->23|>
```

So I assume we have a sequence of ***data-frames***:

```
{<|"cat"->5,"dog"->7|>,
<|"cat"->11,"dog"->8|>,
<|"cat"->13,"dog"->11,"bird"->23|>}
```

fed into the function `BarChartRace` that figures out the animation automatically.

I also think that at least 2 ways of animation is possible: via **GIF/MP4**-like and via `Dynamic`/`Manipulate`-like things.

Again this is just a (questionable) thought, anything else along these lines is welcome. Thank you!

## Real data

If one wants to try this on real data, there are many examples. From GDP of countries to currencies to stocks to movie rankings etc. A very clean sample dataset where there is no missing values is `WikipediaData` for colors:

```
data={WikipediaData["Red","DailyPageHits"],
WikipediaData["Blue","DailyPageHits"],
WikipediaData["Green","DailyPageHits"],
WikipediaData["Black","DailyPageHits"],
WikipediaData["White","DailyPageHits"]};
```

One can easily see where swapping action will happen:

```
DateListPlot[(MeanFilter[#1, Quantity[1, "Months"]] & ) /@ data, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green,Black,White},PlotTheme->"Marketing"]
```

[image]

Note the data are absolutely uniform and easy to use - daily basis, nothing missing, all equal length:

```
Length/@Normal/@data
```

> {2320,2320,2320,2320,2320}

Comment: Take a look at gapminder.org.

Comment: I should have been more specific:  https://www.gapminder.org/tools-offline/.  There you'll see an example what those tools can do.  I have not used the software but have enjoyed the TED talks given by Hans Rosling using that software such as https://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_let_my_dataset_change_your_mindset and https://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_the_best_stats_you_ve_ever_seen.

Answer (score 14):

**Update 3:** A custom `ChartElementFunction` that grows and sorts rectangles:

```
ClearAll[sortedGrowingBars]
sortedGrowingBars[t_, cedf_ : Automatic, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{minmaxy = (1 - t) #[[2]] + 
      t (#3[[1, 1]] + {0, Subtract @@ Reverse@#[[2]]})}, 
  {EdgeForm[], 
   ChartElementData[cedf /. Automatic -> "Rectangle", o][{{#[[1, 1]], 
     (1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]]}, minmaxy}, ##2], 
   Opacity[1], Text[Style[NumberForm[
     Round[N[(1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]]], .01], {3, 2}], 16], 
      Offset[{10, 0}, {(1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]], 
         Mean[minmaxy]}], {-1, 0}], 
    Text[Style[#3[[1, 2]], 16], 
      Offset[{-10, 0}, {First@First[#], Mean[minmaxy]}], {1, 0}]}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];
values = RandomSample[Range[10], 5];
starts = ConstantArray[0, 5];

data = Thread[values -> 
   Transpose[{Ordering @ Ordering @ values, labels, starts}]];


Animate[BarChart[data, BarOrigin -> Left, "BarStartingValue" -> 1, 
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.9], 
   ChartElementFunction -> 
     sortedGrowingBars[t, "FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Right],
   PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max@values}, All},
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600], 
 {t, 0, 1, 1/50}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Update 2:** if we pass ranks, labels and starting values as metadata for each data element we can combine `sortBars` and a slightly modified version of `growingBar` to get a `ChartElementFunction` that gives the desired result:

```
ClearAll[growingBar, sortBars, racingBars]

growingBar[t_, cedf_: Automatic,  o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   {EdgeForm[], 
    ChartElementData[cedf /. Automatic -> "Rectangle", o][
     {{#[[1, 1]], (1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]]}, #[[2]]}, ##2], 
    Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[(1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]], .01], {3, 2}], 16], 
     Offset[{10, 0}, {(1 - t) #3[[1, 3]] + t #[[1, 2]], Mean @ Last @ #}], {-1, 0}], 
    Text[Style[#3[[1, 2]], 16], 
      Offset[{-10, 0}, {t, 1} {First @ First @ #, Mean @ Last @ #}], {1, 0}]} &;

sortBars[t_, cedf_: Automatic, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{minmaxy = (1 - t) #[[2]] + 
      t (#3[[1, 1]] + {0, Subtract @@ Reverse @ #[[2]]})}, 
  {EdgeForm[], 
   ChartElementData[cedf /. Automatic -> "Rectangle", o][{#[[1]], minmaxy}, ##2], 
   Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[ N@#2, .01], {3, 2}], 16], 
     Offset[{10, 0}, { Last@First@#, Mean[minmaxy]}], {-1, 0}], 
   Text[Style[#3[[1, 2]], 16], 
     Offset[{-10, 0}, { First@First@#, Mean[minmaxy]}], {1, 0}]}] &

racingBars[t1_, sortspeed_: 1, rest___] := 
  If[t1 >= 1, sortBars[sortspeed (t1 - 1), rest][##], growingBar[t1, rest][##]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];
values = RandomSample[Range[10], 5];
starts = ConstantArray[0, 5];

data = Thread[values -> Transpose[{Ordering@Ordering@values, labels, starts}]];

Dynamic @ BarChart[data, 
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  "BarStartingValue" -> 1,
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartElementFunction -> racingBars[Clock[{0, 2, 1/100}, 10, 1]], 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max@values}, All}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Use `sortspeed = 10;` and `racingBars[Clock[{0, 1 + 1/sortspeed, 1/100}, 10, 1], sortspeed]` to make sorting 10 times faster than growing:

[image]

If we replace `starts = ConstantArray[0, 5]` with `start = RandomSample[Range @ 10, 5]` (to give each bar its own starting value) we get

[image]

**Update:** A custom chart element function to sort the bars:

```
ClearAll[sortBars]
sortBars[t_, cedf_: Automatic, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{minmaxy = (1 - t) #[[2]] + t (#3[[1, 1]] + {0, Subtract @@ Reverse@#[[2]]})},
   {EdgeForm[], 
    ChartElementData[cedf /. Automatic -> "Rectangle", o][{#[[1]], minmaxy}, ##2], 
    Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[ N @ #2, .01], {3, 2}], 16], 
     Offset[{10, 0}, { Last @ First @ #, Mean[minmaxy]}], {-1, 0}], 
    Text[Style[#3[[1, 2]], 16], 
       Offset[{-10, 0}, { First @ First @ #, Mean[minmaxy]}], {1, 0}]}] &
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];

values = RandomSample[Range[10], 5];
```

Attach to `values` the ranks and labels as metadata :

```
data2 = Thread[values -> Transpose[{Ordering @ Ordering @ values, labels}]];

clock2 := Clock[{0, 1, 1/100}, 3, 1]

Dynamic @ BarChart[data2, 
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartElementFunction -> sortBars[clock2], 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max@values}, All}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  "BarStartingValue" -> 1]
```

[image]

**TODO:** (Hoping that we have not painted ourselves into a corner) find a way to combine `growingBar` and `sortBars` with two synchronized clocks.

**Original answer:**

For starters, for the easier part, we can use a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[growingBar]
growingBar[t_, cedf_: Automatic, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   {EdgeForm[], 
    ChartElementData[cedf /. Automatic -> "Rectangle", o][
      {{#[[1, 1]], t #[[1, 2]]}, #[[2]]}, ##2], 
    Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[t N@#2, .01], {3, 2}], 16], 
      Offset[{10, 0}, {t, 1} {Last@First@#, Mean@Last@#}], {-1, 0}], 
    Text[Style[#3[[1]], 16], 
     Offset[{-10, 0}, {t, 1} {First@First@#, Mean@Last@#}], {1, 0}]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];
values = RandomSample[Range[10], 5];

data = Thread[values -> labels];
```

We can use `Clock` + `Dynamic` to dynamically update the parameter passed to `growingBar`:

```
clock1 := Clock[{0, 1, 1/100}, 15, 1]

Dynamic[BarChart[data, 
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartElementFunction -> growingBar[clock1], 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max @ values}, All}, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image]

Use `growingBar[clock1, "FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Right]` to get

[image]

**TODO:** I think we can extend this approach by (1) passing the ranks of data elements as metadata, (2) adding another argument to `growingBar` to indicate the vertical positions of the rectangles, and (3) controlling the second argument using a second `Clock`.

Comment: The bar-swapping animation is the key and most challenging part :-) But this is excellent start, @kglr, thank you! A thought cross my mind that basic data structure for each frame could be `Association` -- in that way each specific bar can be tracked easily.

Comment: Cool bar-sapping action! +1. I updated my question a bit to help brainstorming. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: This is great and a very important question, bravo Vitaliy. With all the programming that has gone into @kglr 's answer, I wonder whether it might not be relatively easy to switch to graphics primitives with rectangles that would get re-sorted every time the sorting order changes.

Answer (score 3):

The simple switching of the lider can be done easy:

```
values = Table[RandomReal[{0, i}, 5], {i, 1, 35}];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];

anim = Table[
   data = Sort@Thread[values[[i]] -> labels];
   BarChart[data[[All, 1]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
    LabelingFunction -> After,
    ChartLabels -> Placed[data[[All, 2]], Before],
    PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 5 + Max@values[[i]]}, All},
    Axes -> False,
    ImageSize -> 500, GridLines -> Automatic],
   {i, 1, Length@values, 1}];
```

[image]

However, it works without any nice effects like fading etc..

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this is not what the question is about :-) Many folks here understand it is easy to change the order and height of the bars. The smooth animation is the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Graphics` with parametrized `Rectangle` primitives:

```
ClearAll[racingRectangles, ranks]

ranks = Ordering @* Ordering;

racingRectangles[t_, spacing_: .1][starts_, ends_, labels_, cd_: "Rainbow"] := 
 Module[{ord = Ordering @ starts}, 
  MapThread[{#4, EdgeForm[Darker @ #4], 
     Rectangle[{0, #3}, {(1 - t) # + t #2, #3 + 1 - spacing}], 
     Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[(1 - t) # + t #2, .01], {3, 2}], 16],
       Offset[{10, 0}, { (1 - t) # + t #2, #3 + (1 - spacing)/2}], {-1, 0}], 
     Text[Style[#5, 16], Offset[{-10, 0}, { 0, #3 + (1 - spacing)/2}], {1, 0}]} &, 
    {Sort @ starts, 
     ends[[ord]], 
     ranks[(1 - t) starts + t ends][[ord]], 
     ColorData[cd] /@ Rescale[ends[[ord]]], 
     labels[[ord]]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomWord["Noun", 5];
starts = RandomReal[{0, 2}, 5];
ends = RandomSample[Range[10], 5];

Dynamic @ Graphics[
  racingRectangles[Clock[{0, 1, 1/100}, 15, 1]][starts, ends, labels],
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max @ ends}, {0, Automatic}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[racingRectangles[t][starts, ends, labels], 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 1 + Max @ ends}, Automatic}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]], 
{t, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

**TODO:** Make sorting smoother when rankings change.